# Rendering rdlc report through asp.net MVC 5 by controller and begin form helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, rdlc

I am using asp.net MVC 5 and want:
1-to render and open my rdlc report through controller, I already do same job by creating web form page and rendering the report through it, but I know that isn't the best for me.
2- another thing I want when my report load , I want message or prompt ask me what the Id number.

here is my empty controller
public class ReportsController : Controller
{

```
    // GET: /Home/Export
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

the report path in my project
href="~/Reports/Reports/Salaries_Details_Card.rdlc"
and dataset path
href="~/Reports/Dataset/Salaries_AllowansesDataSet.xsd"

what I want is
1- action in that controller to render local report in my project and pass parameter called CODE_ID from my database .
2- in the view "Begin form helper" to load the report and pass parameter asking for CODE_ID by prompt
the code I want is something like the following but I don't know how to do it

```
//
public ActionResult PRF(int id)
        {
            string fileType = "PDF";
            LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "PRF.rdlc");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path)) { lr.ReportPath = path; }
            else
            {
                return View("Index");
            }
            var adof = db.Config.Find(9).ConfigValue;
            var cm = db.PRFs.Where(x => x.ID== id).Select(z =>
            new {
                StaffName = z.StaffList.StaffName,
                IndexNo = z.IndexNo,
                ID = "PRF" + z.ID,
                CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                WINGSAMMOUNT = z.Ammount,
                WINGSTripNO = z.Comments,
                SentToFianceBy = User.Identity.Name.ToString().Replace("GLOBAL\\", "").Replace(".", " ").Replace("mhdiyad", "Iyad"),
                SentToFianceDate = z.Act_Date,
                AdminOficer = adof

            }).ToList();

            //{ cm = db.Trip.Where(x => listOfSearchedIds.Contains(x.ID)).OrderBy(y => y.ID).ToList(); }
            ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", cm);
            lr.DataSources.Add(rd); string reportType = fileType;
            string mimeType; string encoding; string fileNameExtension;
            string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" + " <OutputFormat>" + fileType + "</OutputFormat>" + " <PageWidth>210 mm</PageWidth>" + " <PageHeight>280 mm</PageHeight>" + " <MarginTop>1 mm</MarginTop>" + " <MarginLeft>1 mm</MarginLeft>" + " <MarginRight>1 mm</MarginRight>" + " <MarginBottom>1 mm</MarginBottom>" + "</DeviceInfo>";
            Warning[] warnings; string[] streams;
            byte[] renderedBytes;
            renderedBytes = lr.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
            //return File(renderedBytes, mimeType, "PRF_" + id.Replace(",","-"));
            return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);

        }
public ActionResult DeleteRole(string RoleName)
        {
            System.Web.Security.Roles.DeleteRole(RoleName);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteRole", "ManageAccess", new { RoleName = @role }, new { @Class = "btnInActive" })
```

Comment: Are you just trying to render the report and trigger a download, or are you trying to render the output of the report as something embedded in the page? If the latter, what is your expected output format?

Comment: I make rdlc report in my project and i want to render it as PDF, but when report loading  I want prompt ask for Id number , after that loading page and report

Comment: like MS access when open report containing parameter , prompt popup asking for ID for example

Answer (score 0):

RDLC reports have the option to render as a PDF, which is fairly useful if you don't want to use the Report Viewer control (which requires a WebForms page or a view which uses the WebPages syntax) - granted, you can use routing to "hide" the .aspx extension, if that's the concern.

Assuming you aren't trying to retain support for browsers which are no longer supported by their vendors, you can use either an embed:

```html
<embed id="report-viewer" src="" style="width: 100%; min-height: 1200px;" />
```

or an iframe

```html
<iframe id="report-viewer" src="" style="width: 100%; min-height: 1200px;"></iframe>
```

Either one will leverage the browser's built-in PDF rendering engine. The primary difference is whether you want the PDF to be directly affected by other things on the page (the embed) or to be isolated (the iframe). Both are valid and part of the HTML5 spec (note that I'm **not** referring to frames or framesets - those are deprecated).

If you do need some sort of legacy support, you can use [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) or similar to embed a PDF viewer. It would look something like this:

```html
<iframe id="report-viewer" src="~/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=YOUR_ACTION_URL_HERE" style="width: 100%; min-height: 1200px;"></iframe>
```

Not sure if an embed works with PDF.js, but I assume it would.

I'm not a huge fan of throwing an alert in a user's face immediately on page load, but something like this probably gets you close (I'm assuming jQuery is available, but the plain JavaScript isn't much different):

```js
$(function() {
    // Select the viewer element - this won't change, so keep a reference to it
    let $viewer = $('#report-viewer');
    
    // Set up the base of our updated src URL
    let url = '@Url.Action("prf")';
    
    // Ask for CODE_ID value --> should probably add some validation here
    let id = prompt('Code?');
    if(id) {
        // If value of id is *something*, append it to base URL and update the viewer's src attribute
        url += '?id=' + id;
        
        $viewer.attr('src', url);
    }
});
```

If you're using PDF.js or similar, you would amend the code above to prepend the URL for PDF.js to the updated URL before setting the src attribute:

```js
$(function() {
    // Select the viewer element - this won't change, so keep a reference to it
    let $viewer = $('#report-viewer');
    
    // Set up the base of our updated src URL
    // Include the PDF.js URL at the beginning
    let url = '/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=@Url.Action("prf")';
    
    // Ask for CODE_ID value --> should probably add some validation here
    let id = prompt('Code?');
    if(id) {
        // If value of id is *something*, append it to base URL and update the viewer's src attribute
        url += '?id=' + id;
        
        $viewer.attr('src', url);
    }
});
```

The style attributes on the embed/iframe are arbitrary - I settled on that as something that more or less allows the PDF to render pretty close to full size. Adjust as makes sense for your layout.